# Como usar parametros en Power BI con una Consulta SQL

Tags: sql, powerbi, parametros, powerquery

Buen dia.

Tengo la siguiente consulta power query:

`let  Source = Sql.Database("Servidor","BaseDatos", [Query="Select * from table t where t.date between CONVERT(Date,'"&Text.From(StartTimeParameter)&"' ) and CONVERT(Date,'"&Text.From(EndTimeParameter)&"' "]) in Source`

donde **StarTimeParameter** y **EndTimeParameter** son los parametros, estos los declare de tipo Texto y los llene con un listado de Fechas, que saque con otros parametros de tipo **Date**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si al parametro le activo el **Enable Load**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No hay ningun error en el visual, pero no me da la opcion de seleccionar otras fechas, ya que solo aparece la que se le asigna en **current value**

Con el listado que lleno los parametros las uso para darles un valor en el visual.

Si le desactivo el **Enable Load**, en la parte de relaciones me deja asignarle un parametro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene despues de que agrego un filtro con el campo **StartDates**, me aparece el siguiente erro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces vuelvo a activar el **Enable Load**, pero ya no me deja seleccionar los parametros en la lista de fechas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.